# How to compare year month and day in java?

Tags: java

I'n my application i want to sort the "MyDate" class so, my teacher show me how to sort but how can i compare years first and then the rest?

```
    Comparator<MyDate > dateCompare = new Comparator<MyDate >() {

            @Override
            public int compare(MyDate o1, MyDate o2) {

                int dd1 = o1.getDateDay();
                int mm1 = o1.getDateMonth();
//////years to compare ???????????????????
                int years1 = o1.getYear();

                int dd2 = o2.getDateDay();
                int mm2 = o2.getDateMonth();
//////years to compare ?????????????????
                 int years2 = o2.getYear();

                if (mm1 > mm2) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (mm1 < mm2) {
                    return -1;
                } else { // ==

                    if (dd1 > dd2) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (dd1 < dd2) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }; 


    Collections.sort(list,dateCompare);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the most significant field first. With a `Date` that is `year`. 
Also, there is no need for a trailing `else` since the `if` and `else if` conditions `return`. Something like

```
if (years1 > years2) {
  return 1;
} else if (years1 < years2) {
  return -1;
}
if (mm1 > mm2) {
  return 1;
} else if (mm1 < mm2) {
  return -1;
}
if (dd1 > dd2) {
  return 1;
} else if (dd1 < dd2) {
  return -1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank's i should copy this code on top of the conditions ?

Comment: This is how I would write `compare` if that's what you mean.

Comment: But the code in the qeustion work fine! it's beacuse i'm new in java, and i have very bad teacher :) and you very help me thank you very much!

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compare `years`. This does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `before()` method of `Date` objects to compare the dates, it'll make writing code for your task very simple.  Of course, that means that you have to convert your `MyDate` objects to `Date` but it should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in functionality of the `GregorianCalendar` class to do this in a single line.

```
return new GregorianCalendar(years1, mm1 - 1, dd1).compareTo(new GregorianCalendar(years2, mm2 - 1, dd2));
```

Note that the `- 1` in the month arguments are needed because the `GregorianCalendar` constructor uses a month value in the range of `0` to `11`.

Comment: Yikes! Don't show anyone new to programming the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. That mess will kill any and all interest in programming.

Comment: Sadly, any new programmer will eventually encounter those classes in existing programs.  And in this particular case, `GregorianCalendar` does exactly what is required.

Comment: But you're right; I should have asked whether OP was using Java 8, and given a similar answer using `java.time.LocalDate`.